# RestEasyClient Encoding UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, resteasy

I'm on a not UTF-8 System. Therefore the Client sends the Json allways in the Systems default encoding format, independent of the fact that Json is defined as UTF-X only. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The in the RestEasyClient used ApacheHttpClient4Engine uses in the buildEntity method a DeferredFileOutputStream. So you need to overwrite the behavior there with something like this [Utf8RecodingDeferredFileOutputStream](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/report/https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/report/Utf8RecodingDeferredFileOutputStream.java.java) or set the default encoding to -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

It's also commanded that you set the variant when you create the entity to UTF-8.

`Variant variant = new Variant(MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), language, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
Entity.entity(request, variant)`